# Finding all complex eigenvalues near the unit circle of a large matrix (n around 10k-100k) with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, eigenvalue

I am studying wave propagation in periodic material and need to computes slowness surfaces which are obtained by computing polynomial eigenvalues of some matrix.
Given that I am only interested in propagative waves, only eigenvalues near the unit circle should be researched.
Is there an efficient way to computes those given we do not know the number of values we are searching ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please improve your question with some code and what you tried to accomplish your goal! :)

Comment: Actually said matrix are not in So or Un since they also have eigenvalues outside of the unit circle, we do know that they have some on the circle but that is all...

Comment: This might be better suited for one of the other se sites. Perhaps computational science or mathematics.

Comment: The function eigs should be what you are looking for. Try playing with its parameters sigma and k.